# flow diverter for a nonstandard tub installation

Tags: bathtub

I installed an antique clawfoot tub in a tiled & grouted sunken recess (originally a built-in japanese-style soaking tub) which required me to install an s-shaped tub outlet, so as to clear the lip of the tub as shown in the photo.

To divert flow up to the shower head, I tried installing a shower flow diverter valve on the end of the s-pipe, but the flow through the diverter is so restricted that when I want to fill the tub, only a thin jet of water exits the valve outlet into the tub while water backs up all the way to the shower head, which then dribbles like crazy.

I did a temporary fix by screwing a pipe cap onto the end of the s-pipe to block it completely when I want to use the shower head and then unscrewing it when I want to fill the tub, which yields unrestricted flow into the tub with no dribble from the shower head.

This is a clumsy fix, but I cannot find a diverter valve for the end of that s-pipe which provides full flow (like the ordinary tub spout diverter with the pull knob, which will not fit on the end of that s-pipe) without backing up and causing the shower head to dribble.

Does anyone here have any ideas about how to address this problem, short of plumbing in a completely new faucet set/flow diverter/shower head assembly?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the "look" is already rather "industrial" just put a 1/4 turn ball valve on the end of the pipe. Hole the same size as the pipe when open, shuts off fully when shut.

[image: Ball Valve Image from Zoro.com, no affiliation]

The picture implies that you could also possibly remove the blind cover from a hole in the tub to get a more direct path for a straight pipe stub that would take a normal tub spout, if you'd like a "less industrial" appearance.

Or replace the coupling and "S-bend" with two elbows and two straight nipples, which would allow the normal tub spout to screw onto the end of the second straight nipple.